# How to start using Autodesk Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, bim

I am a new user of Autodesk Forge and I am stuck in the very first step. I cannot figure out what to do after I created an app on Forge's website. Can you please help me with this? I would appreciate it if there are any resources that I can use as I searched the internet and could not find anything.

I would like to do with Forge is to import my BIM from Revit to Forge, but I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you already created an app, you probably were on this website [Autodesk Forge](https://forge.autodesk.com).

The third button in the navbar "Getting started" will redirect you to [Learn Forge](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/) where you can find a lot of resources to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Autodesk recently released their new Forge tutorials that are meant to guide developers through the whole process of creating applications on the Forge platform.

You can find the new Forge tutorial here: https://forge-tutorials.autodesk.io/

If you need more information on all the Forge APIs, you can have a look at the API documentation on the main Autodesk Forge website: https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/documentation